# Help Identify SMD components

Tags: components, identification

I'm trying to repair a water damaged PCB. Wondering if anyone has any ideas how to identify these two components.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Help+Identify+SMD+components

Comment: Qxx usually refers to transistors. 6B is not much info, but it's most likely a generic npn transistor

Answer (score 2):

You could unsolder them and check if there are any markings on the backside of the component. They might not be dead and just need to be resoldered.

[Here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/) is a ressource to find components based on their markings

---

As the comment mentioned, they are likely MOSFET or BJT given the Q markings (they also can be other less common transistors like JFET).

Possible matches for the 6b [Here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/6b)

And for the TG [Here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/tg)

---

Q17 Might be [2sk302](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/2/s/2sk302_toshiba.pdf)

Q18 might be [BC817-25](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/b/c/bc337%2C_bc817%2C_bc817w_series_nxp.pdf)

---

You can go through the list and check the datasheets for size match.